# How to get .so file to show up in package?

Tags: package-management, compiling, shared-library

As many of you know by now, I'm building a package :)

I am so close to getting it finished so I can upload it to my PPA, but there is still one slight problem: the shared library (.so file) doesn't want to go into the package.

Okay, here is what I have in my control file:

```
Source: jsoncpp
Priority: extra
Maintainer: ****** 
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 7)
Standards-Version: 3.8.3
Section: libs
Homepage: http://jsoncpp.sf.net

Package: jsoncpp-dev
Section: libdevel
Architecture: any
Depends: jsoncpp0 (= ${binary:Version})
Description: JSON parsing library for C++
 jsoncpp is a C++ library that makes it easy to
 read / write JSON data.
 .
 This package contains the development tools necessary
 to create applications that use jsoncpp.

Package: jsoncpp0
Section: libs
Architecture: any
Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}
Description: JSON parsing library for C++
 jsoncpp is a C++ library that makes it easy to
 read / write JSON data.
```

Now, jsoncpp-dev builds fine and the development files show up in the package **but** the shared library does not show up in its package.

Here is what `jsoncpp0.dirs` looks like:

```
usr/lib
```

...and `jsoncpp-dev.dirs`:

```
usr/lib
usr/include
```

My updated Makefile is [here](http://pastebin.com/QWGW765S).

*Please let me know if you need further information.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the result of a rather bad mistake on my part. Somehow `jsoncpp0.install` got renamed to `jsoncpp0install` (without the period).

Anyway, it works now.

Answer (score 2):

You really want to be using the build system (scons) that jsoncpp uses, since it's probably well-tailored for the package. 
Firstly, the package names that you are using should be prefixed with lib, such as libjsoncpp0 (assuming that the resulting file is /usr/lib/libjsoncpp.so.0)
To install the files, you need to have these files listed in the .install files, eg debian/libjsoncpp0.install would have /usr/lib/lib*.so.* to install the right file. libjsoncpp-dev would have the files in /usr/include/* and /usr/lib/lib*.so

The library packaging guide at http://www.netfort.gr.jp/~dancer/column/libpkg-guide/libpkg-guide.html can be complex, but it has some important information about the right way to package libraries so that they integrate well in Debian & Ubuntu.

Also, there are often people available on #ubuntu-motu or #ubuntu-packaging on irc.ubuntu.com to help with questions you may have.

Comment: Ah thank you for the IRC link and pointing me to the packaging guide for libraries. It's actually unfortunate, 'cuz I just uploaded it :( Anyway, I need to fix a few things anyway, so I'll work on that.

Comment: Also, how would I go about getting the package to build with scons? I had a hard enough time building it myself - hence the conversion to a Makefile.

Comment: Don't forget the #debian-mentors IRC channel. It's primarily for helping packaging beginners.